# How to put the EOF command into the same line for the execution of the multiple shell commands

Tags: shell-script, cron

I wanted to execute the the following command into the cron job (similar to this) 
Cron job  does not accept this pattern of commands.
nor I am unable to run in the same line either from the shell.

```
cat > file << EOF
first line
second line
third line
EOF
```

let me know if there is way to execute this in the single line.

I also tried with line break at the end of each line no luck.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't the only way to put text into a file.  You could instead do:

```
$ printf '%s\n' 'first line' 'second line' 'third line' > file
```

After this, `file` contains:

```
first line
second line
third line
```

There are limits on the number and length of strings you can provide as arguments to any command.  This shouldn't be a problem in Linux, as these limits tend to be huge, but other Unix systems or embedded environments may be less forgiving.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$'\n'` in bash to represent a new line

For example, you can use:

```
bash -c "cat <<< first\ line$'\n'second\ line$'\n'third\ line > file"
```

in your cron.

From bash man page:

> Words  of the form $'string' are treated specially.  The word expands to string, with backslash-escaped characters replaced as specified by the ANSI C standard.  Backslash escape
>   sequences, if present, are decoded as follows:
>
> \a     alert (bell)
>   \b     backspace
>   \e
>   \E     an escape character
>   \f     form feed
>   \n     new line
>   \r     carriage return
>   \t     horizontal tab
>   \v     vertical tab
>   \     backslash
>   \'     single quote
>   \"     double quote
>   \?     question mark
>   \nnn   the eight-bit character whose value is the octal value nnn (one to 
>   three digits)
>   \xHH   the eight-bit character whose value is the hexadecimal value HH (one or two hex digits)
>   \uHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the 
>   hexadecimal value HHHH (one to four hex digits)
>   \UHHHHHHHH the Unicode (ISO/IEC 10646) character whose value is the hexadecimal 
>   value HHHHHHHH (one to eight hex digits)
>   \cx    a control-x character